# Webpack 4 bundles or ignores dynamic imports

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I'm using dynamic imports in index.js:

```
import('./componentA');
import('./componentB');
import('./componentC');

const myIndexVar = 'My Index Var';
```

index.ts is the entry point in my webpack.config.js.

The result is a single bundle containing all 4 files - index and the 3 components.

My goal is to have each of the files separately in my dist folder, so that index can load the components dynamically on demand at runtime.

i.e. at runtime I'd like to load index.js, and in turn it'll request components a-c via dynamic imports when needed.

Depending on events yields the same results:

```
document.body.onclick = () => import('./componentA');
```

If I try something like this it completely ignores the component and doesn't add it in any way to the dist folder:

```
let componentName = './componentA';

import(componentName);
```

I tried following this article:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Am I misunderstanding what's supposed to happen?

If I'm not on the right track, is there any alternative that can help me reach my goal?

Comment: import is a promise, you have to resolve it. You could add await too

Comment: I know. Are you sure you understood the issue?